# iPhone/iPad: UITextView longest possible text length

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing iPhone/iPad application. I have `UITextView` in which I automatically appending text. How much `UITextView` can handle text without any scrolling lags ? Any average numbers of text length ? Maybe I need to wait for memory warning release `NSMutableString` and set `UITextView` to empty string ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, it'll be able to hold a lot of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the UITextView documentation from Apple, but I definitely would not worry. It will fit a lot. If you want to be safe, do what (i think) you suggested and have the UITextView become empty when a memory warning is called.